# tf.data.Dataset.window example from the documentation fails

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use an example from the [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#window) for `tf.data.Dataset.window` and the example from the documentation is failing.

Code derived from the documentation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(7).window(2)
next_element = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(next_element))
```

Produces this error (trace removed):

```
TypeError: Can not convert a _VariantDataset into a Tensor or Operation.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError: Fetch argument <_VariantDataset shapes: (), types: tf.int64> has invalid type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._VariantDataset'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a _VariantDataset into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

So `iterator.get_next()` is returning a `VariantDataset` rather than the usual tensor.

**TF Version: 1.13.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window produces dataset like structure that is supposed to be returning pairs {1, 2} in your case. Have no idea how to use it properly or why it exists, but managed to make it work like that:
import tensorflow as tf

```
import tensorflow as tf

nxt = (tf.data.Dataset
       .range(7)
       .window(2, 1, 2, True)
       .flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(2))
       .make_one_shot_iterator()
       .get_next()
      )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(nxt))
```

Answer (score 1):

@y.selivonchyk provided the correct answer that helped me understand this. I am adding a second example of using sliding window to help elucidate the correct approach for people who stumble upon this. Notice in particular that window size and batch size are equal.

```
import tensorflow as tf

window_size = 3
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(20)
ds = ds.window(size=window_size, shift=1, stride=1, drop_remainder=False)
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(window_size))

next_sample = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(next_sample))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('EOF')
            break
[0 1 2]
[1 2 3]
[2 3 4]
[3 4 5]
[4 5 6]
[5 6 7]
[6 7 8]
[7 8 9]
[ 8  9 10]
[ 9 10 11]
[10 11 12]
[11 12 13]
[12 13 14]
[13 14 15]
[14 15 16]
[15 16 17]
[16 17 18]
[17 18 19]
[18 19]
[19]
EOF
```