# Error using tensorflow dataset window operation in graph mode with a Session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I cant run the tensorflow dataset `window` examples in graph mode. This

```
def test_window_graph_mode():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(7).window(3, 2, 1, True)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(next_element))
```

crashes - while this

```
def test_window_graph_mode():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(7)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(next_element))
```

works fine. The error is

```
TypeError: Fetch argument <_VariantDataset shapes: (), types: tf.int64> has invalid type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._VariantDataset'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a _VariantDataset into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

The examples dont demonstrate the user of `make_one_shot_iterator` and `get_next` -- I picked that up from google searches. Is there some other interface to using Window in old style graph mode tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine if you add the line,

```
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda x:x.batch(2))
```

before the line,

```
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Complete working code is shown below:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(7).window(3, 2, 1, True)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda x:x.batch(2))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(next_element))
```

For more information, please refer this Stack Overflow [Issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56436701/tf-data-dataset-window-example-from-the-documentation-fails) and [Issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429307/how-to-use-windows-created-by-the-dataset-window-method-in-tensorflow-2-0).

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!